# Python Data Loading slow performance

Tags: python-3.x, performance, pandas, parallel-processing, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to read excel and bulk upload data to SQL Server Table. Data Loading works perfectly but it is taking longer than expected time. 28,000 record is taking 80 sec. I need to load 2-3 GB file in several occasions. I'm quite new to Python, Can you please take a look at the script and let me know if you can optimize the script to improve performance ?

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import timeit


def _get_file_path():
    print('Loading GL Delta file Path... ')
    file_name = \
        'FormPF_Paloma_GLExtract_07312017.xlsx'
    basedir = 'C://Users/XXXXX/PycharmProjects/ETLApplication/Extraction/XXYY/GL/InputFile'
    full_path = os.path.join(basedir, file_name)
    print('Loading File Path Completed.')
    return full_path


def _get_connection():
    engine = \
        sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            'mssql+pyodbc://XXXXXXXXX?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
        )
    return engine


def _process_file():
    sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
    table_name = 'XXXX_GL_File'
    connection = _get_connection()
    file_path = _get_file_path()
    print('Established Connection..')
    print('Reading GL Delta Excel File.....!!!!')
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
    gl_data_frame = xls.parse(sheet_name, index_col="ID")
    print(gl_data_frame)
    print('inserting GL Delta data in Database..')

    gl_data_frame.to_sql(table_name, connection, if_exists='append')
    print('GL Delta Data loaded Successfully!')


def __main__():
    try:
        start_time = timeit.default_timer()
        print('#### STARTING DATA LOADING PROCESS #############')
        _process_file()
        elapsed_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
        print('#### Total Execution Time in milliseconds: #############')
        print(elapsed_time)
    except:
       print('Exception Occurred! ')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

Comment: If `pandas.to_sql()` ends up using pyodbc's `executemany()` underneath, then you might be running to this: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/120

Comment: Thank you. So do we have any other way to improve performance ?